# How to integrate PayPal embedded simple payments into an Android app

Tags: android, paypal, integration

I am trying to create an app that allows users to send money to various merchants based on their selection criteria. It will be single payments only. I have setup my app with things I could find on the developer site, but it only allows a single payment to my account.

The way the app will work is the user will have a list of merchants to choose from, which will also contain the e-mail of their PayPal account. Once the merchant and amount is selected, and the user clicks the submit button, the credentials for that user as well as the amount of payment will be passed up to the PaymentActivity for processing.

Currently, I have various amounts that can be checked, which get passed to the PaymentActivity, but I can't find a way to pass the different merchants through.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ methods to send amount to multiple receivers.